# Explain the phrase "Oh, He is smart like my shoe" - Chivalry

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

In Chivalry: Deadliest Warrior and I think also in Chivalry: Medieval Warfare, the Knight has a taunt phrase where he says "Oh, He is smart like my shoe!".

Does this have any deeper connotations than what is immediately obvious? It seems fairly nonsensical. Perhaps that is the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is an insult - his shoe would be an inanimate object that isn't smart at all, lacking any sort of brain, so saying that someone is smart like his shoe is implying that really, they aren't all that smart at all.

Comment: You are just stating the obvious.

Comment: An obvious answer is still an answer (and as far as I can tell, the right one; the phrase is so nonsensical as to perhaps be an inside joke from the developers, but that's going to be hard to confirm).

Comment: @Philipp Perhaps, but they asked for a meaning, and this is about the best meaning that I can come up with, obvious or no.

Comment: Maybe it's just my twisted sense of humor, but the phrase doesn't seem nonsensical at all to me, and this is exactly how I interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

Shoes can be 'smart' as in, Oh those shoes look smart.
The wit is the irony of the beginning of the sentence "You are smart," (compliment) to finish as "like my shoe!" (insult comparing someones intelligence to an inanimate object)